# Streaming a video to multiple WPF clients

Tags: wpf, wcf, streaming, video-streaming

I need to stream a file from my server to several clients. I'm not sure which approach to take. I found [Windows Media Services](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/server/server.aspx) but all posts I read are three years old, and all examples are in C++. The content also primarily relates to Windows Server 2003 and/or Windows Media Player 9.

Is this the approach for streaming rich content to WPF clients? Can it really be so, that I cannot leverage the strengths of WPF, but I am forced to interact with DirectShow?

I noticed that my Windows Media Player 12 has some features about streaming content to other plaers, could this be leveraged? It seems like a nice approach that I don't have to go all in with Media Server/services.

What is the approach to this using WPF? Say I want to make 10 clients simultaneous stream the same file across the Internet - or "subscribe" to the same broadcast...

Comment: Do you have access to Expression Encoder and Silverlight ? That might be a better solution ?

Comment: No, not on clients, they are wpf only. Thinking about Rolling my own streaming server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I have to use the [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) protocol and Windows Media Server.